# Giving attributes to a Div inside a LiteralControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following line in my code:

```
GroupContent.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div id='TempDivId'>"));
```

How can I attach attributes to that div?

**Edit:**

The Div's are created dynamically, and every div have a button. What I'm trying to achieve is when I'm clicking on a button, only that specific Div receives the conetenteditable attribute.

A sample from my code:

```
    foreach (TblComment Index in ListDGComm)
    {
        ImageButton EditComm = new ImageButton();
        EditComm.ImageUrl = "../../../images/edit_property.png";
        EditComm.ToolTip = "edit";
        EditComm.CssClass = "EditComment";
        EditComm.ID = Index.Cnum;
        EditComm.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(EditComment); 

        string TempDivId = Index.Cnum + "1";

        GroupContent.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div id='TempDivId' class='CommContent'>"));
        GroupContent.Controls.Add(Comment);
        GroupContent.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
     }

    private void EditComment(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    ImageButton Ebtn = (ImageButton)sender;
    string DivId = Ebtn.ID + "1";
    }
```

I need to locate the Div with the DivId and attach the attribute to that Div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question seem a little broad, anyway **all** this approaches can help:

**Server-Side**

```
GroupContent.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format("<div id='TempDivId' myAttr1='{0}'>", 
                                             'myAttr1Value')));
```

**Client-Side**

```
var myDiv = document.GetElementById('TempDivId');
myDiv.myAttr1Value = 'thisIsMyAttr1Value';
```

**JQuery Client-Side**

```
var myAttr1Value = 'thisIsMyAttr1Value';
$('#TempDivId').attr('myAttr1',myAttr1Value)
```

**EDIT**

but if you want a suggestion do something like this

```
var yourDiv = new  HtmlGenericControl("div");
yourDiv.Attributes.Add("yourAttributeName","yourAttributeValue");
GroupContent.Controls.Add(yourDiv );
```

**EDIT**

Seems you need something like this:

**C# page code behind**

```
var index = 0;

      var htmlDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
      htmlDiv.Attributes.Add("id", string.Format("_myDiv{0}", index));
      htmlDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "CommContent");

      var editComm = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor();
      var image = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage { Src = "../../../images/edit_property.png" };
      editComm.Controls.Add(image);

      editComm.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("MakeEditable('{0}')", string.Format("_myDiv{0}", index)));
```

**JavaScript**

```
  function MakeEditable(divId) {
    var div = document.getElementById(divId);
    div.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');

  }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that only from the server side?

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help! I edited my question so it will be more clear. I need to use the ID (The ID gets generated dynamically) somehow so only the specific Div will get this attribute.

Comment: mmh probably you need to paste some of your code to let me figure what change you really need sorry :)

Comment: @Wolf just edited, you should follow that strategy to accomplish your task, have a nice day :)